# tool for java dependency analyze

Tags: java, dependency-analysis

When maintenancing software of enterprise system, specifing influence part againist fixing part is important.
But, I think the maintenance teams that establish the method of specifing influence part are very few.
At least, my team don't establish such method.

I am maintaining enterprise system that made of Java + SpringFramework, 
and I search for tool that specify dependency relationship between components and specify influence part againist fixing part automatically.

I want to specify dependency not only between Java classes, but also between below:

- database table and class
- classes that mediated by interface
- client side component and server side component
  (e.g. Java and Flex, Ajax, Curl, HTML... )

I can search tools at vendor homepage, but I want to know tool that actually applied to software maintance field and sucessed.
Could someone recommend me a tool?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is called [tracability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceability#Software). Usually, this starts in the [requirements phase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Requirements_Traceability#Tracing_beyond_the_requirements), and often ends there because it's extremely time-intensive to provide full tracability down to source code level. I think the only pieces of software where it's routinely done are systems where the vendor is held legally liable for errors. Typically that means embedded systems where an error can lead to injury or death.

I don't know which tools are actually used for this, but I'd look at the automotive, aviation and medical equipment industries.